# Ошибка компиляции async Qt в macOS

Tags: c++, macos, g++, асинхронность, clang

Заметил, что Qt не компилирует пример с async

untitled2.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>


void foo()
{
    std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
}

void bar()
{
    std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    auto h1 = std::async(std::launch::async, foo);
    auto h2 = std::async(std::launch::async, bar);
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибки про сборке Qt'ом

```
12:36:46: Выполняются этапы для проекта untitled2...
12:36:46: Настройки не изменились, этап qmake пропускается.
12:36:46: Запускается: «/usr/bin/make» 
/Applications/Qt/5.6/clang_64/bin/qmake -spec macx-clang CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=x86_64 CONFIG+=qml_debug -o Makefile ../untitled2/untitled2.pro
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/g++ -c -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -g -std=gnu++11 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -Wall -W -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -I../untitled2 -I. -I/Applications/Qt/5.6/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang -o main.o ../untitled2/main.cpp
../untitled2/main.cpp:18:15: error: no matching function for call to 'async'
    auto h1 = std::async(std::launch::async, foo);
              ^~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/future:2357:1: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Fp = void (&)(), _Args = <>]: 'future<void>' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.8
async(launch __policy, _Fp&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/future:2383:1: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Fp = std::__1::launch, _Args = <void (&)()>]: no type named 'type' in 'std::__1::__invoke_of<std::__1::launch, void (*)()>'
async(_Fp&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
^
../untitled2/main.cpp:19:15: error: no matching function for call to 'async'
    auto h2 = std::async(std::launch::async, bar);
              ^~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/future:2357:1: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Fp = void (&)(), _Args = <>]
async(launch __policy, _Fp&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/future:2383:1: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Fp = std::__1::launch, _Args = <void (&)()>]: no type named 'type' in 'std::__1::__invoke_of<std::__1::launch, void (*)()>'
async(_Fp&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
12:36:47: Процесс «/usr/bin/make» завершился с кодом 2.
Ошибка при сборке/установке проекта untitled2 (комплект: Desktop Qt 5.6.2 clang 64bit)
Во время выполнения этапа «Сборка»
12:36:47: Прошло времени: 00:01.
```

Если собирать из терминала, то вот эти команды работают:

```
clang untitled.cpp -o untitled --std=c++11 -lc++
g++ -std=c++11 untitled.cpp -o untitled
```

Как сделать, чтобы все собиралось из Qt'а?

Comment: Проверяйте настройки сборки в Qt. Можете сюда вывод консоли сборки приложить.

Comment: "MSVC does not require any special flags and enables the C++11 features by default, but GCC or Clang require -std=c++0x." https://woboq.com/blog/cpp11-in-qt5.html